# If condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
    x["next_dtScraped"] = 
if x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1):
    x["dtScraped"].shift(-1)
else:
    None
```

So basically I want to create a column in which it'll return the next row of one column but only if another columns'row is equal to that column's next row. The code above didn't work, due to a syntax error. I'm not really sure if this is the way to go.

```
+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|        |   home_team   |     away_team     |      dtScraped      |   next_dtScraped    |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  81965 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 17:40:48 | 2017-09-26 17:54:38 |
|  76817 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 17:54:38 | 2017-09-26 17:56:05 |
| 236234 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 17:56:05 | 2017-09-26 18:04:43 |
| 192767 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:04:43 | 2017-09-26 18:08:38 |
|  13448 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:08:38 | 2017-09-26 18:17:56 |
|  38306 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:17:56 | 2017-09-26 18:23:14 |
| 106907 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:23:14 | 2017-09-26 18:36:36 |
| 235751 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:36:36 | 2017-09-26 18:45:56 |
| 143897 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:45:56 | 2017-09-26 18:47:34 |
| 206117 | APOEL Nicosia | Tottenham Hotspur | 2017-09-26 18:47:34 | 2017-09-28 19:22:49 |
| 112775 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 19:22:49 | 2017-09-28 19:37:41 |
| 128744 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 19:37:41 | 2017-09-28 19:49:06 |
| 238778 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 19:49:06 | 2017-09-28 19:54:15 |
|  37271 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 19:54:15 | 2017-09-28 20:13:15 |
|  81647 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:13:15 | 2017-09-28 20:17:44 |
|  65930 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:17:44 | 2017-09-28 20:20:31 |
|  45845 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:20:31 | 2017-09-28 20:21:50 |
| 110165 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:21:50 | 2017-09-28 20:35:16 |
|   4856 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:35:16 | 2017-09-28 20:40:36 |
| 148769 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:40:36 | 2017-09-28 20:54:01 |
|  34760 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 20:54:01 | 2017-09-28 21:02:34 |
| 182633 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 21:02:34 | 2017-09-28 21:13:20 |
| 230996 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 21:13:20 | 2017-09-28 21:20:41 |
|  66761 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 21:20:41 | 2017-09-28 21:25:49 |
| 243059 | AS Monaco     | Besiktas JK       | 2017-09-28 21:25:49 | 2017-09-28 21:43:19 |
+--------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So I'd like, when the teams change, to not get value from the previous team. So the index  206117, last line of APOEL x Tottenham would have null in the column next_dtScraped

Comment: Provide some sample data please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
x["next_dtScraped"] = np.where(x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1),x["dtScraped"].shift(-1),None)
```

Comment: This one worked perfecly, I just had to add a conversion to datetime. Code used:
'code' x["next_dtScraped"] = np.where(x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1),x["dtScraped"].shift(-1),None)
x["next_dtScraped"] = pd.to_datetime(x["next_dtScraped"])

Comment: @IvoFilipe glad it help nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce:

```
mask = x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1)
mask = reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, mask)
if mask:
    x["dtScraped"].shift(-1)
else:
    None
```

`x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1)` gives you a list of boolean, so using reduce you can see if it's stricly equals.

For your error i don't know what you tried to do, but you should post the error you got so we can know how to help.

EDIT : Think i've got what is your syntax error, try this:

```
x["next_dtScraped"] = x["dtScraped"].shift(-1) if (x["away_team"] == x["away_team"].shift(-1))     else        None
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df["next_dtScraped"] = df["next_dtScraped"].apply(lambda x: df["dtScraped"].shift(-1) if df["away_team"] == df["away_team"].shift(-1) else x)
```

Or:

```
x["next_dtScraped"] = x.apply(lambda c: c["dtScraped"].shift(-1) if c["away_team"] == c["away_team"].shift(-1) else None)
```

Not sure which one you need :)